# How to handle race-condition in ember-data when live-polling filtered array and saving records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, race-condition

I have an Ember Route that polls for new records every 5 seconds.

Here is the Route's `model` function:

```
model: ->
  @store.filter "event", "status": "created", (instance) =>
    instance.get("status") == "created"
```

Here is the Route's polling mechanism:

```
setupController: (controller, model) ->
  @_super(controller, model)
  @startPolling() unless @get('polling')

startPolling: ->
  @set('polling', true)
  Ember.run.later @, ->
    @poll()
  , 5000

poll: ->
  return unless @get('polling')
  @model().then =>
    @poller = Ember.run.later @, ->
      @poll()
    , 5000
```

This functionality works fine ***except*** in one scenario.

A user may alter the `state` attribute of an `Event` model.

For example, a user can choose to `hide` an `Event` instance, which calls the following code:

```
changeStatusAndDisplayFlash: (event, status) ->
  event.set('status', status)
  event.save().then (event) =>
    @queueFlashMessage(event)
```

***The problem is*** that if the Events poller is currently making a request and the individual record `save` promise returns before the poller's request completes, the record will have its state reverted when the poller's request finally does complete.

This is a classic race-condition, however, I am unsure of how to handle this in ember-data.

***In short, I'm trying to figure out how to:***

Honor the state of a model based on the most recently ***triggered*** request rather than the most recently ***completed*** request.

So if we have the following requests (in order of when they were initiated):

1. Original `model` request which returns the filtered collection.
2. Polling request that updates the filtered collection (with new models and/or updated attributes to existing models).
3. Save request that updates the attributes of a single model in the collection.

And the order of completion is such:

1, 3, 2

I would like the outcome of request #3 to be the final result, however, as it stands, the last request to complete (which is currently #2) is the one that sets the outcome.

Does anyone know of a strategy for achieving this in ember/ember-data?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: To me it looks like every time you poll you return a full list of records rather than just the new records.. Is this a requirement? Can you only have the new records returned?

Comment: @jmurphyau — Come to think of it, yes, I can only have the new records returned.  Should only require slight modifications to the server controller action and Ember `filter` query.